# Is it possible to log programs executed from the drop down menu?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

I'm trying to achieve similar functionality of bash history, but for programs executed from the drop down menu.

For example, clicking and executing "Applications -> Calculator" would leave an entry in a log file noting that the user executed this program.

Is there a built-in solution to this, or maybe a simple third-party utility that can handle this?

Here is a link to an example of the menu I am talking about, in this case in Xubuntu, I believe it is the GNOME menu?

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: What Operative System are you using? What desktop version are you using? Try to take a screenshoot so we can know what do you mean by "drop down menu".

Comment: Included more info!